# Killing form and principal bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, principal-bundles

In the proof of [proposition 4.1](https://math.mit.edu/events/talbot/2011/library/hitchin_stable_bundles_integrable_systems.pdf), Hitchin states that the killing form can be used to make the identification $\operatorname{ad}P^* \cong \operatorname{ad}P $ where $P$ is a principal $G$-bundle for a semisimple group $G$.

Any clues on this mysterious link?

Comment: Why is this mysterious in any way? A bundle metric allows you to identify a vector bundle with its dual. The Killing form provides a bundle metric, whenever $G$ is semisimple.

Comment: Thank you! I am confused  as a vector bundle is $\operatorname{GL}_n $ bundle, so what about the $G$-torsor structure of the principle bundle in a given Grothendieck topology? Can we say that "A metric on a principal  G-bunle allows you to identify the principal bundle with its dual when $G$ is semisimple"?

Comment: The adjoint bundle is a vector bundle.